# Show all posts shows a blank white page in WP 4.2.2

Tags: posts, bug

In show all posts I have changed the number of items pe page from 20 to 500 and after that I got a timeout as it could not display all the posts. And now every time I go to show all posts I get a white blank page and no posts and I am not able to change the number of items to be displayed on the page.

Comment: Turn on `WP_Debug` and look for errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install and activate *User Meta Manager* plugin. Go to `Users -> User Meta Manager`. Under your user click on `Edit Meta`. From pull down list of meta keys select `edit_post_per_page` and click `Submit`. Change the value to 10 and click on `Update`. All done.